# Find distribution when given Moment generating function

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the distribution that corresponds to this moment-generating function.

$$ M(t) =\frac{1}{3e^{-t}-2} , \quad t < \ln \frac 3 2 $$

I can not even consider where to start.
Any push in the right direction would be appreciated! 
Thanks:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My best advice for situations like this is to be familiar with the forms of the MGFs of your special distributions.

In particular, consider the following.

**Claim**: If $X\sim\operatorname{Geom}(\theta),$ then the MGF of $X$ is $$M_X(t)=\frac{\theta e^t}{1-e^t(1-\theta)}=\cfrac1{\frac1\theta e^{-t}-\frac{1-\theta}\theta},$$ where $t<\ln\frac1{1-\theta}.$

**Proof**: Observe that $$\begin{align}\Bbb E\left[e^{tX}\right] &= \sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx}\theta(1-\theta)^{x-1}\\ &= \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{t(x+1)}\theta(1-\theta)^x\\ &= \theta e^t\sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{tx}(1-\theta)^x\\ &= \theta e^t\sum_{x=0}^\infty\left[e^t(1-\theta)\right]^x.\end{align}$$ Now, $e^t(1-\theta)=|e^t(1-\theta)|,$ so when $e^t(1-\theta)<1$--equivalently, when $t<\ln\frac1{1-\theta}$--the series at the end is a convergent geometric series, so $$M_X(t):=\Bbb E\left[e^{tX}\right]=\theta e^t\cdot\frac{1}{1-e^t(1-\theta)}=\frac{\theta e^t}{1-e^t(1-\theta)},$$ as desired. $\Box$

Can you see what $\theta$ you should use, here?

Comment: It would be 1/3? then my probability function would be (1/3)(2/3)^x for x = 0,1,2... .

Comment: That's it, yes!

Comment: Thank you so much :) You made it all click together in my head.

Comment: @CameronBuie For example if I have that $$ \rho(s)=\frac{2}{(2-s)(3-s)}, \ 0\leq s\leq 1$$ is a probability generating function of a distribution. How can I calculate the distribution of this? I don't understand where to start to calculate this distribution, I suppose that I have to compute $P(X=x)$ with this function?

Comment: @Knight: I suppose that my best advice is the same as I gave in my answer, but your comment doesn't actually seem to be closely related to my answer or this question. I suggest that you pose it as a new question, instead. Don't forget to include your thoughts and efforts on the problem, as people will be more likely to respond if you do.